# Port PHP encryption/decryption to Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to port over the following code to Node.js with no luck.

```
    $output = false;
        $key = hash( 'sha256', self::SECRET_KEY );
        $iv = substr( hash( 'sha256', self::SECRET_IV ), 0, 16 );


        if( $action == 'e' ) {
            $output = base64_encode( openssl_encrypt( $string, self::ENCRYPT_METHOD, $key, 0, $iv ) );
        }
        else if( $action == 'd' ){
            $output = openssl_decrypt( base64_decode( $string ), self::ENCRYPT_METHOD, $key, 0, $iv );
        }

        return $output;
```

This is where I am so far, but it's either spitting out gibberish or I get one of several errors.

```
    var crypto = require('crypto'),
      algorithm = ENCRYPT_METHOD,
      password = SECRET_IV;

    function encrypt(text){
      var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, sha256(SECRET_KEY), sha256(SECRET_IV).substring(0,16))
      let p = Buffer.from(text, 'utf8').toString('base64');
      var crypted = cipher.update(p,'utf8','base64');
      crypted += cipher.final('base64');
      return crypted;
    }

    function sha256(data) {
      return crypto.createHash("sha256").update(data).digest("hex");
    }

    function decrypt(text){
      var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, sha256(SECRET_KEY), sha256(SECRET_IV).substring(0,16));
      decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
      var dec = decipher.update(text,'base64','utf-8');
      dec += decipher.final('utf8');
      return dec;
    }
```

I've tried decoding/encoding with base64, but this also does not work. Once I added setAutoPaddding to false, I started making some progress. I found on one thread that this is an issue when encoding/decoding from one language on Node.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if I am not mistaken it would be easier to work with "transform" stream in nodejs.   examples of transform streams are compression / crypto / ...   as I recall streams als would better handle encoding.   streams are very flexible.

Comment: @jcuypers - I haven't seen this yet. I'll dive into it. Big thanks

Comment: Did you check the output of hashes before encrypt? You don't need update and final. The update is useful for adding more data, the final applies padding if needed then encrypts.

Comment: Sorry, the hashes of encrypt? I'm not encrypting in JS. I've tried using crypto.createDecipher() without final and update, but no luck. Can you give an example?

Comment: Can I recommend using a library developed by security experts instead of rolling your own? CipherSweet does searchable encryption in both [PHP](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet/) and [Node.js](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet-js). (A stable v1.0.0 of the JS version is coming soon, probably within the week.)